# iOS Swift stop duplicate HTTP requests

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to Swift and I am using Swift 4. I have an action that sends an HTTP request when a button is tapped. On the backend it inserts a record into the database. All of this works correctly, however sometimes even though I tap the button once Swift sends the HTTP request 2 or 3 times and then I get duplicate records. Is there a way to stop that? This is my simple code

```
@IBAction func submitAction(_ sender: Any) {

    let url:URL = URL(string:ConnectionString+"insert_location")!
    var myName = ""
    TableSource.isHidden = true
    let session = URLSession.shared
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringCacheData
    if let fullname = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "fullname") {
        myName = fullname
    } else {
        myName = "UnKnown"
    }
    let address = "Unknown"

    let location = Location[0]
    let parameter = "location=\(location)&latitude=\(latitude!)&longitude=\(longitude!)&name=\(namePlaceStreet.text!)&address=\(address)&profile_id=\(MYID)&fullname=\(myName)"
    request.httpBody = parameter.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
    session.dataTask(with:request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
        if error != nil {

        } else {
            do {
                let parsedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as! [String:Any]
                if let Streams = parsedData["result"] as? [AnyObject] {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        for Stream in Streams {
                            if let notification = Stream["outcome"] as? String {
                                self.coordinates.isHidden = false
                                self.coordinates.text = String(notification)
                                self.submitButton.isHidden = true
                                self.namePlaceStreet.isHidden = true
                                self.topLabel.isHidden = true
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }).resume()
}
```

Comment: Did you try putting in breakpoints, and finding out why the request is sent multiple times?

Comment: check also whether this duplicate is caused by the php script in server

Comment: On which button event is the action fired? Is it `.touchUpInside`? Make sure you block your UI once the action is fired (e.g. hiding the button, showing activity indicator).

Comment: It seems like it’s coming from the swift side since I am seeing sometimes more than 2 calls coming in from 1 click . Since the Swift code is in Async it probably sends it multiple times on occasion . I will try to handle it in swift and see if that solves the issue.

Comment: Right yes it is on touch up inside and I was disable the button as soon as it gets clicked and then check to see what happens

Comment: **Since the Swift code is in Async it probably sends it multiple times on occasion** No this can't happen , this is caused by a problem someWhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is asynchronous so it's better to add an activity indicator begin of the action and remove it in success / error , or disable the button

```
@IBAction func submitAction(_ sender: UIButton) {

   guard sender.isEnabled else { return } // in case for a messy outlet connection

   sender.isEnabled = false 

   .....

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
      sender.isEnabled = true
    }
}
```

Clicking it multiple times is an expected UX so you need to handle it

Comment: that check for `sender.isEnabled` seems excessive.

Comment: If sender is not enabled, no event can be fired.

Comment: The main thread is serial. There cannot be anything in between.